# select a limited amount of results based on column

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, unique, distinct

I've tried checking out this question [sql - distinct + select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890034/select-distinct-select-top-to-merge-multiple-rows) and can't seem to get it tailored correctly to my situation. I am also not on the sql dev team so I don't know all the in's and out's of the database. I'm shooting in the dark here on a test DB. Here is a pseudo sample of my current query:

```sql
select a.name, b.col1, 
from name a, amount b
where a.identifier=b.acctid
and b.col1 != 'test'
```

Example of what is currently returned by query:

```
a.name | b.col1
Jeff     1
Jeff     333
Jeff     77
Jeff     1
Jeff     14
Bob      22
Bob      4
Bob      5
Bob      6
```

And I would like for the results of the query to return the first n(a number I choose) results that are unique based on ColA. For example if n was 2:

```
a.name | b.col1
Jeff     1
Jeff     333
Bob      22
Bob      4
```

Comment: You want the top 2 of each ColA?  What is the name of the column you will use to order this?  Please make your pseudo query and the results columns have the same column names.

Comment: sorry i forgot to update the result sets to match the query, done.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005 or above?

Comment: no idea. like i said i was given very little info as of right now and a very simplistic query just so i'd know column names. Basically if i wait a day or 2 i'll have all the info I need. I'm just not patient and wanted to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+ you can use analytical functions:

```
DECLARE @n INT
SET @n = 2

;WITH CTE AS 
(   SELECT a.name, b.col1, b.col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY a.identifier) Corr
    FROM name a
    INNER JOIN amount b
    ON a.identifier = b.acctid
    WHERE b.col2 != 'test'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Corr <= @n
```

I also changed your query to use explicit joins.

Comment: @TimLehner - Yeap, it is. I changed now, thanks for the heads up

Comment: it doesn't like the declare and set apparently. throws error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: @whitewolfpgh - `ORA-06550`?, so you are using Oracle instead of SQL Server as stated on your question?. In any case, that part was only to explicit the `n` on your question, you can just filter the query without that part and changing `@n` by the number you want

Comment: ya i was told it was sql and the query i was given wasn't language specific. It was a basic select statement. That's the first error I've received so yes it appears its oracle. I told you I was handed a black box.

Comment: hard to tell the difference between sql and pl/sql with a simple select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Create a temp table with that info and another column with an auto-increment value for each ColA type.

Step 2:

Select all the info where the new column < n Value